# I do not understand why the onChange event is not firing

Tags: laravel, select

i am using Laravel v8 Livewire.
I have a blade with
`<select name="event_id" id="event_id" size="" class="form-control" onchange="ChangeDescription">`
the layout file has

```
</head>
<body>

  @yield('content')
  @stack('scripts')
  @livewireScripts
</body>
```

And the blade has

```
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('content')
@push('head')
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('../../resources/js/ChangeDescription.js')}}"></script>
@endpush
<div class="container">
...
```

For testing purposes the function has only one line:
`function changeDescription() {alert('changeDescription');}`

According to W3Schools, (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onchange),
the event should fire when one of the values is clicked.

So, what do I have to do to get the event to fire off?

Comment: in the w3s example the syntax is `onchange=myFunction()` but in your example you're using `onchange=changeDescription` (no parentheses). Generally speaking you shouldn't use `onchange` at all and use `addEventListener('change',...)` which is purely in JavaScript

Comment: To solve your problem instead of changing your code you have two typos: changeDescription should have () after it and you have a capital C in your onchange in select instead of little c in change.

Comment: apokryfos, where do i put the listener?

Comment: imvain2, still not working